# XMLHttpRequest Error | Blob | Angular 5 | Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, xmlhttprequest, firebase-storage

I'm trying to return a blob for a firebase storage upload in an `Ionic 3` app. In the iOS emulator (haven't tested on iPhone yet) it works, but after building for Android and running on phone, it returns the "Loading error". Any idea why this is happening?

```
  loadXHR(url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      try {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.open("GET", url)
        xhr.responseType = "blob"
        xhr.onerror = function () { reject("Network error.") }
        xhr.onload = function () {
          if (xhr.status === 200) { resolve(xhr.response) }
          else { reject("Loading error:" + xhr.statusText) }
        }
        xhr.send()
      }
      catch (err) { reject(err.message) }
    })
  }
```

The file url is for an image which is selected from the phone gallery using Ionic s Camera plugin, then cropped.

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.app.events/cache/1535133947691-cropped.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

To download the BLOB data from the API URL. you can try this code.

```
    loadXHR(url) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          try {

             var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
             oReq.open("GET", URL, true);
             // Define how you want the XHR data to come back
             oReq.responseType = "blob";
             oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
                var blob = oReq.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
                if (blob) {

                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    document.getElementById('bot-img').src = url;
                    // Or read the data with a FileReader
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
                       // reader.result contains the contents of blob as text
                    });
                    reader.readAsText(blob);
                } else console.error('we didnt get an XHR response!');
            };
            oReq.send(null);

         } catch (err) { reject(err.message) }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Test and let me know, if you still face issues. Upvote it so it will be useful to others